# multithreading in regards toTask, async, and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, async-await

I have the following code and just want to make sure I have the concept of multithreading down on a high level.

```
public async Task<List<Category>> GetProjectsByCategoryIDAsync(Int16 categoryid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
            {
                DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                var category = await DbContext.Categories.Include("Projects").Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryid).ToListAsync();

                return category;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**It is my understanding of the following:**

1. async - declares a method to run asynchounously instead of
   synchrounously.
2. Task - declares a method to run as a task on a single thread
3. await - the task waits for the operation to complete.

Where I am a little fuzzy about is the await keyword. Obviously, the benefit of asynchrounous programming is that the method supposedly doesn't have to wait for the task to complete before another request comes in right behind it. But with the await keyword, the task waits until the operation is finished.

With synchrounous programming, everything is processed in a sequential pattern.

How does this methodology allow for requests to come in simultaneously and be executed in a much faster fashion than synchronous programming??

I just need a high level explanation to get the concept down.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Basically, the `await` keyword puts the rest of the body of the `async` method into a continuation which is then run *after* your `ToListAsync` method is finished. This allows the `async` method to not block the current thread. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_AsyncandAwait) for a more detailed explanation of how they work together.

Comment: So when control is returned to the calling method (via the await keyword), this essentially allows simultaneous calls of the async method coming in from a calling method thereby having multiple requests hit the async method asyncrhounsly. Correct?

Comment: I'm biased, but I recommend [my own intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). I try to cover everything you *need* to know without oversimplification.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That cleared things up too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        int i = await DoSomethingElse();
        Console.WriteLine("End " + i);
    }

    public Task<int> DoSomethingElse()
    {
        return new Task<int>(() =>
        {
            // do heavy work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return 1;
        });

    }
```

> With synchrounous programming, everything is processed in a sequential
>   pattern.

The code above is asynchronous, but is still sequential. The difference between that code and its synchronous version (e.g., `public int DoSomethingElse`) is that when you `await DoSomethingElse`, the main thread will be freed to do other work, instead of *blocking* waiting for DoSomethingElse to complete.

What actually happens is: your async DoSomething method will run on thread A and be broken in two.

- the first part will print "Begin" and make an async call, and then **return**.
- the second part will print "End"

After the first part of the method executes, Thread A will be free to do other work.
Meanwhile, Thread B will be executing the lambda expression that does some heavy work.
Whenever Thread B completes, the second part of your method will be scheduled to run on Thread A, and "End" will be printed.

Notice that, while Thread B was executing the heavy work, Thread A was free to do other stuff.

> How does this methodology allow for requests to come in simultaneously
>   and be executed in a much faster fashion than synchronous
>   programming??

In frameworks such as ASP.NET MVC, your application has a finite number of threads available to handle incoming requests (lets call these "request threads"). By delegating heavy work to other threads and *awaiting*, your request threads will be free to handle more incoming requests *while* heavy work is being done.

This diagram, although complex, illustrates the execution/suspension flow of threads executing asynchronous work:

[image]

Notice how at step 6 the thread was yielded, and then step 7 resumed the execution of the method.
As you can see, the `await` keyword effectively breaks the method in two.

Comment: I may have over-complicated things, let me know if I failed to make any of these concepts clear.